# Understanding quantifier rules in sequent calculus

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, sequent-calculus

I am trying to learn sequent calculus for a while and for the life of me, I cannot make sense of the below quantifier rules for [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#An_intuitive_explanation):

|  | $L$ | $R$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\forall$ | $$\Gamma, A[t/x] \vdash \Delta \over \Gamma, \forall xA \vdash \Delta$$ | $$\Gamma \vdash A[y/x], \Delta\over \Gamma \vdash \forall xA, \Delta$$ |
| $\exists$ | $$\Gamma, A[y/x] \vdash \Delta \over \Gamma, \exists xA \vdash \Delta$$ | $$\Gamma \vdash A[t/x], \Delta \over \Gamma \vdash \exists xA, \Delta$$ |

I've already read many related questions here about quantifier rules and I am trying to come up with intuitive explanations for each rule which also explains their eigenvariable condition. Here is my attempt:

$\forall R$ rule:

From the linked Wikipedia page, their explanation goes like this:

> For an intuition about the quantifier rules, consider the rule $\forall R$. Of course concluding that $\forall{x} A$ holds just from the fact that $A[y/x]$ is true is not in general possible. If, however, the variable y is not mentioned elsewhere (i.e. it can still be chosen freely, without influencing the other formulae), then one may assume, that $A[y/x]$ holds for any value of y. The other rules should then be pretty straightforward.

I disagree with that other rules are "pretty straightforward."

$\forall L$ rule:

Suppose $\Delta$ is derivable from the set of assumptions $\Gamma\cup\{A[t/x]\}$. Then, it is true that $\Delta$ is derivable from the *stronger* set of assumptions $\Gamma\cup\{\forall xA\}$.

$\exists R$ rule:

When $\{A[t/x]\}\cup\Delta$ is derivable from assumptions $\Gamma$, since $t$ is an "object" that exists, $\{\exists xA\}\cup\Delta$ is derivable from $\Gamma$.

$\exists L$ rule:

When $\Delta$ is derivable from $\Gamma\cup\{A[y/x]\}$, since $y$ is arbitrary "object", then $\Delta$ is derivable from $\Gamma\cup\{\exists xA\}$.

Unfortunately, it doesn't explain why eigenvariable condition is needed for this rule. This rule could be written as

$$\dfrac{\Gamma,A[t/x]\vdash \Delta}{\Gamma,\exists x A\vdash\Delta}$$

Is there any resources that goes in detail on how quantifier rules can be understood intuitively?

Comment: See [Rules introducing quantifiers in sequent calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030485/rules-introducing-quantifiers-in-sequent-calculus-a-question-about-notation) for universal quantifier. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693478/restrictive-rules-for-lk-system).

Comment: See [Proving soundness of sequent calculus rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524872/proving-soundness-of-sequent-calculus-rules) for the existential quantifier. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619932/why-is-there-a-limitation-on-the-existential-introduction-in-sequent-calculus).

Comment: $(\forall \text L)$ rule: the meaning of $Γ,A[t/x]⊢D$ is that conclusion $D$ (forget for simplicity the fact that $\Delta$ is a multiset of formuals) is derivable form premises $\Gamma$ plus $A[t/x]$. But $∀xA$ implies $A[t/x]$, and thus $D$ is derivable form premises $\Gamma$ plus $∀xA$, i.e. $Γ,∀xA⊢D$.

Comment: The same for $(\exists \text L)$ rule. Regarding $(\exists \text R)$: if $A[t/x]$ (again forget about $Δ$) is derivable from assumptions $Γ$, since asserting $A[t/x]$ implies that "there is something (named $t$) such that $A$ holds of it", we are entitled to conclude that $∃xA$ is derivable from premises $\Gamma$.